# Alternative Way to write string with Quotations

Tags: php, string

How would I make this work in PHP:

```
$string = "<div id="widget14" class="widget widget-124">
     <a href="http://website.com/page.php?id={$pageurl}"><p><span class="hotspot" onmouseover="tooltip.show('<strong>About Us</strong><br/>Learn about us!');" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();"><img class="images_button" alt="About Image" src="{$image_url}" width="172px"/><br/>About Us</span></p></a>
    </div>";
```

Comment: you can use single quotations ' and/or you can escape the quotations with \"

Comment: Reminder that if you are using variables, you need them inside double quotes to be evaluated, or concatenate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = "<div id=\"widget14\" class=\"widget widget-124\">
     <a href=\"http://website.com/cgames/\"><p><span class=\"hotspot\" onmouseover=\"tooltip.show('<strong>About Us</strong><br/>Learn about us!');\" onmouseout=\"tooltip.hide();\"><img class=\"images_button\" alt=\"About Image\" src=\"http://www.website.com/images/logo.png\" width=\"172px\"/><br/>About Us</span></p></a>
    </div>\";
```

Above should work prerfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

No PHP required:

```
<div id="widget14" class="widget widget-124">
   <a href="http://website.com/cgames/"><p><span class="hotspot" onmouseover="tooltip.show('<strong>About Us</strong><br/>Learn about us!');" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();"><img class="images_button" alt="About Image" src="http://www.website.com/images/logo.png" width="172px"/><br/>About Us</span></p></a>
</div>
```

If it absolutely must be a variable:

```
$string = <<<HTML
    <div id="widget14" class="widget widget-124">
       <a href="http://website.com/cgames/"><p><span class="hotspot" onmouseover="tooltip.show('<strong>About Us</strong><br/>Learn about us!');" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();"><img class="images_button" alt="About Image" src="http://www.website.com/images/logo.png" width="172px"/><br/>About Us</span></p></a>
    </div>
HTML;
```

[Heredoc Syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Otherwise you're stucking escaping quotes with back-slashes.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself well enough. It doens't necessarly need to be in a variable, just work in an echo statement like echo "<div id....."; and as I've edited it, there are variables inside the Div.